# Can't add text to textarea on click

Tags: javascript

I have a table of element, and when i click on a td, i show something on atextarea

the problem is when i click, nothing show on the textarea...

what i actually do is that :

```
            td.onclick = (function(textToShow){
                return function(){
                    var textArea = document.getElementById("modification_bloc");
                    textArea.value  = textToShow;
                }
            })(structure[key])
```

HTML code (is .ejs)

```
<form id="modification_bloc" action="modification_bloc" name="modification_bloc" class="hidden" type="post">
    <textarea name="contenu_bloc" id="contenu_bloc"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Sauvegarder modifications"/>
</form>
```

the problem is that my textarea is always empty....

If i do a console.log of "textToShow" i have the text, and if i add the text as a placeholder i can see it in the console but not on the textarea. The innerHTML method works, but the text is obviously not editable ç^^

I don't get what is wrong.

can you help me? **without JQUERY :)**

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/cerz4foe/ The problem is somewhere else that you're not showing us.

Comment: well i can't really reproduce, the html is an .ejs file and the text come from an Ajax request to a node server (he is parsed and everything...)

Comment: just a thought but have you tried textArea.innerHTML = textToShow?

Comment: this works, but i can't edit the text